# Creating translations table in sequelize node express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

[image]

Hello.
I'm trying to create api in node express with sequelize. I understand basic workflows there. But I'm thinking if tere is maybe some easy solution to develop like on screen. I'm creating CV_KNOWN_LANGUAGE row using api and I want to have name and details translated. So I'd like to have only string_id in this place. All strings will be stored in STRINGS table. Obvious is that I can add my own implementation for set and get. It'd create string first and assign created id to field in CV_KNOWN_LANGUAGE. But like I said. I'm looking for more simple solution.

Comment: Using JSON for storing l10n would make it simpler

Comment: It'll be dynamic. I want to allow user input for many languages